# Why We do NOT backpropagate deltas from bias units in Neural Network

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to implement a simple neutral network in Python. My question is when we do backpropagation, why we don't backpropagate deltas from bias units? In the tutorial below, it says so, but I don't get it.

i also pasted my code below. my question is 1) is there any mistake in the code? 2) if I change "W0 = W0 - alpha*np.dot(X_bias.T,L1_delta[:,:-1])" to "W0 = W0 - alpha*np.dot(X_bias.T,L1_delta")", it will throw an error. "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,4) (3,5)" So my question is why do i have to omit the last column in this matrix?

http://outlace.com/Beginner-Tutorial-Backpropagation/

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(num):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-num))

def sigmoid_derivative(num):
    return num*(1-num)

def add_bias(matrix):
    newcol=np.ones((matrix.shape[0], 1))
    return np.hstack([matrix, newcol])


print("Initializing parameters")
alpha = 0.09

X = np.array([[1,1],
              [1,0],
              [1,1],
              [0,1]])

y=np.array([[1],
            [0],
            [0],
            [1]])

W0 = np.random.rand(3,4)
W1 = np.random.rand(5,1)


print("Start iterating")
for i in range(60000):
    X_bias = add_bias(X)
    L1 = sigmoid(np.dot(X_bias,W0))

    L1_bias = add_bias(L1)
    L2 = sigmoid(np.dot(L1_bias,W1))

    L2_error = L2 - y
    L2_delta = L2_error*sigmoid_derivative(L2)
    L1_error = np.dot(L2_delta,W1.T)
    L1_delta = L1_error*sigmoid_derivative(L1_bias)

    W1 = W1 - alpha*np.dot(L1_bias.T,L2_delta)
    W0 = W0 - alpha*np.dot(X_bias.T,L1_delta[:,:-1)


if i%1000==0:
    print("Error after {0} iterations is: {1}".format(str(i),str(np.mean(np.abs(L2_error)))))
```